# Dynamic Where condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a little problem :) I have a list where some arguments are duplicate. I must remove that. I can't use Distinct becouse i must only see at some fields (not all).I think it's great option to use lambda epxressions.

I have a declaration on my object who i working, not the same but the idea is similar.

```
var keys = new string[] {"column1", "column2"};
var repeatedValues = new object[] {5, 15};

var values = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

//MAKE FAKE DOUBLE
values.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { 
            { "column1", 5 }, { "column2", 15 }, { "column3", "test" }, 
            { "column4", "test1" } });

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   values.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> {
               {"column1", i}, {"column2", 10 + i},  "column3", "test"}, 
               {"column4", "test1"}});
}
```

The keys columns always have the same lenght as repeatedValues - but is changed, some the lenghts is 1, other 2,3,5. Not more than 5

The keys is like primaryKeys on database table. It's quite similar. So we looking for duplicates in "primary keys columns" - i think is a good compare.

We see in that example duplicate is has value 5 in "column1" and values 15 in "column2". How i before say i must remove that, but before i must count repeated items.

I try do code like that (i know the func method awalys fail becouse (object)1 == (object)1 always return false, but it's example :

```
Expression expression = null;

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    Expression<Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>> exp = x => x[keys[i]] == repeatedValues[i];

    if (expression == null)
      expression = exp.Body;
    else
      expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, exp.Body);
}

var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Dictionary<string, object>), "x");

var lamba = Expression.Lambda<Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool>>(expression, parameterExpression);

var res = lamba.Compile();
var counts = queryLis.Count(res);
```

But compilator give me a exception
variable 'x' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

It's possible to do this at this way ?

(Not about exception) In other step maybe the expression be asking for example repeatedValues[i] (after for) and it will doesn't know what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the same `Expression.Parameter` that the original expression is referencing.
Making a new `Expression.Parameter` with the same name isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're messing with Expression and the like. If I understood you correctly, you're essentially duplicating a relational database situation with each entry of values being a row of data where the column represents the field name. If that's the case, then you might as well take a page from the database book and work off of an index. After your first snippet, you can get at a cleaned-up list like so:

```
// testing for duplicates
List<Dictionary<string, object>> duplicates = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
List<string> index = new List<string>();
foreach (var value in values)
{
    List<string> keyValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        keyValues.Add(value[key].GetHashCode().ToString());
    }
    string hash = string.Join(",", keyValues.ToArray());
    if (index.Contains(hash))
        duplicates.Add(value);
    else
        index.Add(hash);
}

var cleanList = values.Except(duplicates);
```

EDIT: altered example so that it puts the hash in the same column order each time.

Comment: It's a option, but i try that with HashSet and StringBuilder - it work faster, but if i use expression trees it's work a half faster - i don't beliwe but it's true

Comment: Yeah, this is proof of concept and a starting point for further optimizations.